# App Widget does not appear in the widget list on Honeycomb devices until Launcher is restarted

Tags: android, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android AppWidget does not show up in the menu in honeycomb until reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024025/android-appwidget-does-not-show-up-in-the-menu-in-honeycomb-until-reboot)

It seems like the default launcher in Android 3 (Honeycomb) has a bug. It doesn't seem to refresh the widget list when you install a new application. When you restart the launcher (or restart the whole tablet) the widget will be there, as it should be. Seems like the widget list there is cached, while on earlier versions of Android, and in other launchers this is not the case.

I've followed the instructions in the SDK, and it seems to be working find on other devices, but on Android 3 it never worked right from the first time :(

I've marked my application with `android:installLocation="internalOnly"`
Here's the widget registration in the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".BatteryWidget" android:label="@string/widget_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.flexlabs.action.BATTERY_UPDATED" />
            <action android:name="org.flexlabs.action.dualbattery.SETTINGS_UPDATED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

Please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Honeycomb+ launcher behaves a bit differently than pre-Honeycomb one. It does not display widget in list of widgets until you launch any activity of the application.

See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6ef964dc4395e979/161a79b9a4d0a753?show_docid=161a79b9a4d0a753&pli=1 for more details.

Comment: WOW! Seriously, WOW.. I'm impressed, and slightly disappointed with this decision at the same time. At least now I know what to do to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been trying to figure out this issue for some time now. You're a legend :)

Comment: Ok but what about a widget without any activity at all?