# android 3.0 honeycomb, finding and activating widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb, launcher

Android 3.0 activates widgets differently from 2.x and maybe 4.x

I am trying to figure out how people accomodate this.

Basically on android 2.x the expected functionality is that a widget is downloaded and immediately available for use and the `onUpdate` method is ready to go to make the widget function as desired/

On Android 3.x it seems that several things don't happen the same way:

- After a widget is downloaded it isn't always seen in the list of widgets, until after a restart. (I have seen things detailing "why" this happens, but not why other widgets seem to not have this problem)
- In other cases, a widget is downloaded and is visible in the list of widgets, but added it to the launcher screen doesn't activate it. `onUpdate` seems not to be working, and touch events are not active, until after a restart.

I have seen posts talking about how a boot loader activates widgets when the launcher screen first loads, but I have seen widgets that don't have this problem.

Similarly, I have used that logic to force the launcher screen to reload by changing the phone's locale. But I would like widgets I create to be available without any troubleshooting, how would this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HC+, you have to start any activity associated with the app at least one time after the app is installed, then it should show up in the list.  edit: also app on sdcard has issues see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8555

Edit also yours is a duplicate of [App Widget does not appear in the widget list on Honeycomb devices until Launcher is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736313/app-widget-does-not-appear-in-the-widget-list-on-honeycomb-devices-until-launche)

Comment: thanks that is insightful, what about if you don't have a launcher activity though. No launcher icon, only want a bare minimum widget, is this simply impractical? Is this also the same as what happens on ICS and Jelly Bean

Comment: @CQM still duplicate questions, read through the duplicate I posted in my answer for all the details.  But basically you have to just create a blank dummy activity, just start and then finish right away.

Comment: ah yes, I did read the whole thread on google groups now, insightful. I've used dummy activities before for other hacks, a bit surprised at this outcome but okay. thank you for your responses